# How can I change the loading screen colour without "android:background"?

Tags: android, timepicker, material-components-android

Before my app loads I can change the color of the loading screen using

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FF444444</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However, if I do this then I can no longer load the material design library's `TimePickerView` because it says  `Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimePickerView` and, more importantly, `Attempted to get ShapeAppearanceModel from a MaterialButton which has an overwritten background.`

Once I remove the above `android:background` all is well. Except my loading screen is now white.

So, is there a way to change the loading screen colour without the above XML attribute in the hope that I can get material's `TimePicker` to work? Or perhaps another work around?

(I've found out how to disable the loading screen completely, but the second or so wait is not ideal.)

Comment: Can you try to use `android:windowBackground` instead

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and no luck.

Comment: Try to use `window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(some_color)` right after `setContentView()` call and remove the background from the style... Hopefully this works now

Comment: Try this also set both `android:colorBackground` & `android:windowBackground` to have the same color, and remove `android:Background`

Comment: You're right, Zain. `android:windowBackground` does work. But only when the color comes from `@color/whatever` than a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are the possible solutions (the first solved it):**

1. Use `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:background` >> requires to use a resources color than a hardcoded one (i.e. `@color/some_color`)
2. Use `window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(some_color)` right after `setContentView()` call
3. Set both `android:colorBackground` & `android:windowBackground` to have the same color, and remove `android:Background`